# Why does class 'Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource' not found in a Lumen project and how can I add JSON Resource in Lumen project?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, lumen

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;
```

works and can be retrieved inside a Lumen project. But, using

> ```
> use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
> ```

will return

> Class 'Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource' not found`

So, how can I add `JsonResource` inside a Lumen project?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can check your autoload_classmap.php in vendor/composer folder
otherwise you simply use this use Illuminate\Htt[image]p\Resources\Json\JsonResource;